# [ROS2] topic hz provides wrong rate for larger msgs

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While testing the `ros2_intel_realsense` package on ROS eloquent (Ubuntu 18.04, ROS middleware FastRTPS) I realized, that `ros2 topic hz` reports far lower rates for a `pointcloud2` topic than an explicit C++ subscriber.
The rgbd point cloud has about 5MB/frame and is published at 30Hz.

**C++ subscriber:**

```
[INFO] [pointcloud2_subscriber]: Recived 27 messages in 1.00 s (27.00 Hz)
[INFO] [pointcloud2_subscriber]: Recived 28 messages in 1.00 s (28.00 Hz)
[INFO] [pointcloud2_subscriber]: Recived 30 messages in 1.00 s (30.00 Hz)
[INFO] [pointcloud2_subscriber]: Recived 27 messages in 1.00 s (27.00 Hz)
```

**ros2 topic hz:**

```
average rate: 12.106
    min: 0.022s max: 0.641s std dev: 0.09745s window: 100
average rate: 11.019
    min: 0.022s max: 0.641s std dev: 0.10628s window: 100
average rate: 10.903
    min: 0.022s max: 0.641s std dev: 0.10630s window: 100
average rate: 11.917
    min: 0.022s max: 0.572s std dev: 0.09033s window: 100
```

This difference is quite significant.
Moreover, `ros2 topic hz`seems to cause a considerable load on the system, so that the rate of the C++ subscriber drops from ~25Hz to ~15Hz (ros2 topic hz drops to about 8Hz in this case).

As `ros2 topic hz` is written in python I also tried setting `PYTHONOPTIMIZE=0` as suggested [here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues/165), however with no effect on the results.
For comparison reasons, I tested a similar setup with ROS(1) melodic, where `rostopic hz` provides accurate and stable results.

**Which leads me to the following questions:**

1. What could cause this significant difference of the measured rates? (related to QoS settings?)
2. Is it possible to improve the performance of `ros2 topic hz` in some way?
3. What is the recommended way of measuring rates of larger messages such as point clouds or images in ros2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350753/%5Bros2%5D-topic-hz-provides-wrong-rate-for-larger-msgs/) by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 218 on 2020-04-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2020-05-06**:
`ros2 topic hz` causing an unexpected load on the system and outputing a seemingly lower/bad rate is "known." I thought I had seen work being done on it in the past 6 months, but I can't find anything. Not sure what can be done though. It might be worth opening a bug and see what the maintainers say: https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues

**Comment by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on 2020-05-06**:
@christophebedard thank you very much for your reply. It is good to know, that I am not the only one facing this issue and that this is not caused by my specific setup/configuration. I will go forward and open an Issue on GitHub as you suggested.

**Comment by [Bruno Arieira](https://answers.ros.org/users/54855/bruno-arieira/) on 2020-11-16**:
Hello, the subscriber "pointcloud2", was it developed by you or does it already exist in a package? I need to subscribe to a topic to get the message rate, but without using the "ros2 topic HZ" command due to its latency.

**Comment by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on 2020-11-17**:
@Bruno Arieira `pointcloud2_subscriber` is just a simple C++ subscriber that increments a counter whenever a new message is received with an additional timer callback that logs the number of received messages in a given time interval.
It was actually very similar to the [Simple Cpp Publisher and Subscriber Tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber/) (which also includes a timer in the publisher)
except that I additionally specified the required QoS when creating the publisher.

It was meant just as a quick comparison to `topic hz`. Depending on your use case you might need something more advanced (e.g. include filtering etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some further testing I think I finally found the reason for the considerable difference in the message rate between `ros2 topic hz` and my custom C++ subscriber.

As it turns out, `ros2 topic hz` uses `Sensor data QoS` profile, while I used `Default QoS` in my C++ Subscriber.
If i change the QoS setting to match `ros2 topic hz`, the results are comparably low.

So this issue appears to be more related to proper choice of QoS settings and not specific to `ros2 topic hz`. However, it points out, that measuring message rates with ROS2 CLI might be ambiguous, as the actual rate depends on the QoS settings of the subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) with karma: 218 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2020-06-15**:
does changing your subscriber's QoS setting to match `ros2 topic hz`'s QoS cause a high system load as well? Because, while they may match, a high system load (for either of them) is still not normal.